# How to configure Centos Web Panel Module in Blesta

Tags: centos, control-panel

I have Blesta server Provisioning system.

I have installed Centos Web Panel Module in Blesta, however, I cannot get it to auto-provision services on the CWP VPS.

If I attempt to manually activate services from Blesta, the web browser eventually throws an error 503.

The cron jobs are configured on both (the CWP server itself, and in Blesta)

The server logs show nothing else regarding any success or failure to provision, just that the cron is scheduled to run and does run every 5 minutes.

The Blesta documentation contains absolutely no instructions on how to install and more importantly, how to configure the CWP module (even though Blesta developers, Phillips data, are the ones who created the module).

I have provided Blesta staff with root access to both my CWP server and Blesta, and after 2 days, I have received nothing more from them other than to say "nothing is wrong" (and yet nothing provisions so clearly something IS wrong!!!)

Has anyone here any experience with Blesta CWP module and any suggestions on how to get this working?